# Monitoring timers in a windows service

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services, monitoring

I have the following code in my windows service

```
  var timeToWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
        var interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        var t = new Timer((s) =>
            {
                tracker.ProcessAuditLogs();
            }, null, timeToWait, interval);
```

Are there any ways I can monitor this timer, by polling or any other mechanisms, and get back information to display on a windows form, with information such as

- Last executed time (e.g., process executed 7 mins ago)
- Next execution (time of next execution, e.g., if it's a 20 min interval, and 5 mins has passed since the last execution, it will show '15 mins to next execution'

Comment: You can save the information “Last Execution Time” and “Next Execution Time” of the timer in the DB table and poll that information from DB on periodic interval.
Let’s say if you poll the DB in every 5 minutes then get “Next Execution Time” from DB table and subtract it from the Current time and display the remaining time for the execution.

Comment: This code isn't going to work, the timer object will be garbage collected.  Recording the DateTime.UtcNow when you start the timer is a simple way to get what you want.

Comment: Why would it be garbage collected? Could you elaborate a little? I thought it will run continuously for as long as my windows service is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a standard way with the Timer class. I would advise to encapsulate a timer object in a parent class like this :

```
public class MonitoredTimer {

    private Timer _timer;
    private int NextExecutionTime;
    private int LastExecutionTime

    public MonitoredTimer(TimerCallback callback,...) {
        _timer = new Timer((s)=>callback(s);UpdateExecutionTimes());
    }

    public int GetLastExecution(){
        return LastExecutionTime;
    }

    ...
}
```